# Is fixing this removable drive possible?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have an 8GB removable drive, which shows up in the Windows **Computer Management** window as:

[image: Drive status]

At this point this drive is unusable.

This is a USB drive that I have used in the past to install Windows/Ubuntu/HackOSX etc.  At this point I assume that the drive is ready for the bin, but is this the case? Is there a tool out there that will restore this drive to its former usefulness, or will I need to buy a new one?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Disk Management in Windows to delete all the partitions shown (after any backup of data) and then configure as one volume ir whatever you need.  Or are you trying to acomplish something else?